# How can I set my mapview to automatically zoom in on user's current location?

Tags: xcode, location, mkmapview, zooming

When I click on the "Map" button in my tab bar, it pulls up my Map View Controller, and shows the user's current location on the mapview (I'm using the following code):

```
[mapview setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

Super easy. But if I want the map to automatically zoom in on the user's current location, how do I go about doing this (in xCode)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i think this is what you need

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
    //some code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[mapview setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow];

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you are looking for

```
    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    region = (MKCoordinateRegion){(current user location).location.coordinate, (current user location).locationCoordinateSpan};        
    [theMapView setRegion:region animated:NO/YES];
```